# jQuery accordion is always expanded / refresh required to work

Tags: jquery, refresh, accordion, required

Many apologies if answered elsewhere, but I've searched and not found this scenario answered. Always something opposite actually desired or similar...

I have a website, [www.namesakeradio.com](http://www.namesakeradio.com/). It seems that any time someone first visits the website, and sometimes at random after that, the accordion is all-open / expanded all the way.

All you have to do is then refresh the page and it looks and works perfectly fine. This works the same way on all of the pages I have it on - a mobile page, and a music page.

Is there perhaps a simple js function that would auto-refresh a container (i.e. the accordion container) whenever a page is visited, that would curtail this issue? Or anyone is welcome to view the page source, or I am happy to include the source here... I just don't want to code-clutter if I'm not supposed to. This is my first js question here, so please advise on anything you wish for me to add, retract, etc. and I will do so.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because jquery is not completely downloaded from time to time, but your site tries to initialize the accordion plugin.

I suggest you move all you JavaScript files to the end of your page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="js/picturefill.min.js" class="picturefill" async="async"></script>
<script src="http://streams4.museter.com:2199/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });

        $(".selector").collapsibleset("refresh");
    });
</script>
</body> <!-- CLOSING BODY TAG IS HERE -->
```

That way you can be sure, that your accordion function gets executed, as soon as everything is donwloaded.

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: Ah!  Ok, I always thought I was supposed to put js at the top so it would load first. :P I will do that now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have been toying around with placing it in different ways. Still getting the same random results. I tried leaving the script sources at the top, and the script itself at the bottom just before the </body> tag. Tried moving both the source lines and script to bottom, reversing it, etc. I still see the same issues cross-browser and platform. I'm just missing something.

Comment: I'm sure it is unorthodox, what about moving the "refresh" call to it's own location? I assume by context that is calling for a refresh of the accordion container? If so, can I separate that out, and just call it at the bottom of the page? Perhaps even put a one tick wait before refresh? I dunno I'm just throwing out ideas here :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally found a solution by endless tinkering. I don't know why it works, but it seems to work so I'll post it here for anyone that might come across it in the future in hopes this may work for them:

I put the following jquery script request before all others at the very top:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I then put all other non-jquery script source definitions in after that, then finally I put the following at the bottom of the "stack":

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In closing, I put the acordion script at the bottom of the page html, just before the  tag.

All of that seems to have resolved any issues with new visit loading and random loading after that. I really appreciate the bumps in the right direction. Thank you very much!